# get html table column id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html Table with 1 row and 1 column like this:

```js
<table id="backlog">
  <colgroup> <col width="200"></colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td id="91" tabindex="0" class="mark">BackLog</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and I want to get the column id with jquery. How coul i do this?
 I have tried this:

```
colId = $("#backlog td:first").attr('id');
```

but its not working.

Comment: It work fine for me see http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/ePCvY/ ...what error it showed in console

Comment: @TiagoHuezo Have you placed your piece of code under document.ready? When are you performing this activity onload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting an `undefined` error with the posted code, it's likely that the DOM is not loaded by the time you're running the jQuery function. Make sure you wait for the DOM to load before you execute your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready() {
    colId = $("#backlog td:first").attr('id');
}
```

Or, alternatively, the jQuery shortcut:

```
(function($){
    colId = $("#backlog td:first").attr('id');
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will only ever be the one row/col

```
var colId = $("#backlog td").attr("id");
```

Comment: Is there indeed _exactly_ one `td` element?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    colId = $("#backlog td:first").attr('id');
});
```